# Filter all fields in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I wish to have a Search field for my [Tabulator Datagrid](http://tabulator.info/) where a search will find all occurrences in all fields of the tabulator of my search-criteria. If possible I want to use the Filter-API. Very much like in ([DataTables](https://datatables.net/)).

I have seen the "Applying Multiple Filters" section in the Docs and wonder if this is the only way to achieve this? Perhaps there is already an API which does what I want?

Answer (score 0):

you can nest [filters](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.2/filter) too

```
table.setFilter([
    {field:"age", type:">", value:52}, //filter by age greater than 52
    [
        {field:"height", type:"<", value:142}, //with a height of less than 142
        {field:"name", type:"=", value:"steve"}, //or a name of steve
    ]
]);
```